# VS2013 Cordova Application, how to use *.less in mobile application?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013, less

How I would be able to use vs2013 and compile *.less files with Cordova application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try web essential extension http://vswebessentials.com/features/less
and cordova tools https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/cordova-vs.aspx

Comment: Actually tried it with http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2014/04/29/refactoring-your-css-with-less-in-visual-studio-web-essentials.aspx these instructions and it doesn't actually work, can you give more correct instructions?

Comment: I'have installed web essential and created a less file when i save webessential generate the corrisponding css. Which is your problem?

Comment: I did the same nothing is happens when you use Cordova project

Comment: Tested on Cordova Project with same results. Try to reinstall webessential or check configuration.

Comment: Can you add a github link to your demo project?

Comment: Success I was just needed to save something and re-compile it.

Comment: One problem, after you close the solution it's failed to load again. Can you explain?